# Switching ISP to save money good idea?

Tags: united-states, utilities

My ISP (Spectrum) recently raised the price of my monthly internet bill to $70+.  There are competitors in my area going for the $50 range with equal or faster speed.  Is it possible to "haggle" with spectrum to lower the price by calling them, or just switch provider to get their introductory pricing?

Has anyone done this and can give some insight?  Is this too much hassle or any other cons that make it a bad idea? or just stick to my current provider even though their price is roughly $20 per month more than competitors' introductory pricing?

Comment: I kept my cost down with Cox for quite a while this way.  Only the first time did I actually mention leaving. After that, I just called up every year to renew the discount.

Comment: Remember that introductory prices rise after the introductory period is over.  How much will it increase?

Comment: Yes, always call and ask for lower. When they say no, threaten to cancel and go to a competitor. When they still say no, ask for the cancellation department. *If* the cancellation department still says no, cancel and go to a competitor. Spectrum is the worst bunch of rent-seekers anywhere. This is literally on my to do list this week, and typically is every one to two years.

Comment: In general, *any* pressure on companies you deal with to provide better and cheaper service and compete with substitute products and services is good practice. They aren't your friends, they want your money.

Comment: In my experience, some telcos are pretty liberal with their new-customer promotions. 11 months in, I'd call, and they'd pretty much always just reapply the same discount for another year. At worst, I could just say I'd like to unsubscribe, so that my partner can subscribe as a new customer, and then they'd usually give the same discount, because they don't want to go through the headache of all that.

Comment: You have to be *actually* prepared to cancel. Giant corporations spend a lot of money researching how to tell whether you are bluffing. They know.

Comment: Comcast plans all increase in price at 6 and 12 months, so I have a 6 month repeating calendar item to call them and switch plans to whatever is currently cheapest. Saves me quite a bit of money.

Comment: Be careful with competitors.  Right now you have a service you know works.  We tried to switch to Windstream at a business because Windstream claimed 74MB up and down and they wanted the upload speed for live streaming since Spectrum only offers 10MB up and the business account cost $170 vs the $50 for Windstream.  In the end the service was 35MB down and <1MB up.  The supposed free first month no cancellation fees ended up being $180 bill with no way to return their hardware.

Comment: @rtaft so you found a bunch of other dissatisfied customers and sued Windstream, right?

Comment: @user253751 filed a complaint on BBB site

Comment: I've called several times to get a lower prices. They said no and I had to switch. I now use my own wireless router so I don't have to change the username and password of devices when I switch. I'm getting ready to ditch Spectrum.

Answer (score 26):

> Is it possible to "haggle" with spectrum to lower the price by calling
> them, or just switch provider to get their introductory pricing?

Yes it is possible. You can find plenty of anecdotal examples of calling their ISP or cable provider and threatening to switch and getting the ISP to agree to a lower rate, or other special feature.

> Is this too much hassle or any other cons that make it a bad idea?

If you do switch expect that they will want to do a professional install. That can come with a cost in both time and money.  If you bought your own hardware you might need new hardware or you will have to rent it from them, which could reduce the price advantage when switching. You might have to return some hardware to the old provider.

If you do switch and were using one or more email addresses related to that ISP service, then you have to factor in the change in email address. If you had storage thorough your ISP make sure that you have pulled everything from whatever storage you were using related to your contract.

Comment: All these are the reason why I buy my own gear. No hassle of having to switch out anything. I always refuse the ISP hardware because, IMO, they are garbage anyways.

Comment: Often companies will have a "customer retention" department that current customers can reach out to to discuss deals on their current contract. Talking with them with an idea of how much you would pay to a competitor or as a new customer is a good starting point.

Comment: @Nelson: I tried that for a while, but Comcast plans change prices regularly, and if you switch plans, they insist the new plan doesn't work with your personal hardware. I got burned a couple of times before I caught on :(

Comment: @MooingDuck Got burned, as in, you listened to them but in fact you could've just changed plans?

Comment: It’s also possible that the other providers are merely reselling Spectrum circuits (or fiber) at a loss but with a commitment and higher prices. The end result can be A) same or slightly lower quality of service and slower actual speed with poorer tech support and/or B) a plan that seems like a bargain at first but ends up costing more in the end after all fees are included and all term commitments honored.

Comment: *If you do switch expect that they will want to do a professional install* => I've switched 3 ISPs and it was all self-installed since the cables are already there. *If you do switch and were using one or more email addresses related to that ISP service* => 99.9% of users don't use such emails.

Comment: @Nelson you always know ISP hardware is garbage because it's free

Answer (score 9):

This may get closed as a "shopping question" or technical question, and off topic... But in brief:

As with cell phones or other mostly standardized subscription services, getting the best price often requires being willing to switch every few years to take advantage of "new customer" discount offers.

Remember to consider all the prices. There may be installation costs. They may want to rent equipment to you,or (especially for optical fiber) you may need to buy equipment and have it installed. Most will offer multiple options for speed/price tradeoffs; decide what you actually need. (I've been paying for 200Mbps and usually measuring closer to 300; I don't feel any need right now to pay more and go up to a nominal-gigabit connection.)

Some ISPs may offer discounts through your employer; that saves me $5/month.

Be aware that if you have been getting email through your ISP, changing services will likely require changing email addresses, with the hassle of updating all your friends and any online accounts to use the new email address. One way around this is to set up a permanent mailbox somewhere (your school may offer this service), make a one-time change to have everything and everyone point to that, and then have it forward to wherever you actually are -- or access it directly, if the mail service permits it. You may also be able to set your old address to forward to the new one, at least for a limited time; contact your current ISP for details.

More advice on how to manage this efficiently is almost certainly available on the technical areas of Stack Exchange; I don't have a specific pointer handy.

Comment: The 1990s called and want their 300kbps back. There are 3.5 orders of magnitude difference between that and a gigabit connection.

Comment: M, not k. Thanks for the catch. So quickly we take these speeds for granted; I remember when 300 baud was advanced technology... ""The lowest acceptable performance often equals the best performance the user has ever seen."

Comment: The other standard for acceptable performance is "the same speed the website/software developer had in the testing lab"

Comment: @keshlam Well it was indeed a big step up in the 1970s from a KSR 33 at 110 baud to a Decwriter at 300 baud.

Comment: Obligatory music cue: Frank Hayes' song, _When I Was A Boy_.

Comment: @keshlam - In February 2001 I had 250 kilobit/sec (consistent) cable broadband installed. My pal, as most people were, was still on 56k dial-up. That's on a good day. 33k more like. He came to see me and asked me to show him how fast it was. I fired up Napster and searched for a few hip-hop tracks, as he was a fan of that. He took one look at the progress bars visibly moving and exclaimed 'I want this!'. Now my UK ISP is offering 1 Gb/sec but I am sticking with 300 Mbit.

Comment: @keshlam I have a similar one, "the maximum acceptable price equals the lowest price I have ever seen."

Comment: Beyond certain threshold speed is irrelevant, so long as the latencies are good. For close to a decade I've worked in offices where we had 30-50 Mbps symmetrical shared among five to ten people, and it always worked fine. Granted, no one did video calls, but music or videos from YT in the background do happen.

Comment: True, but that threshold depends on what you're doing, how much of it involves off-site resources, how much is happening in realtime/affecting user response times, and how much is running in parallel. As with processor speeds. As with most things, actually. Being able to do a large git checkout or application install  or system update in a relatively short time is definitely a luxury, but it's one that improves my productivity, and since I do things like that for fun,.. Some tools are just nice to have, even if one can work without them.

Answer (score 3):

Switching internet providers can be like switching most other utilities: You write a letter and all you notice is that you suddenly pay less money per month.

Just some things you need to be wary about:

- Make sure the new provider uses the same technology and can reuse the existing hardware. For example, switching from DSL to cable modem or fiber can require some hardware changes in your home which might take a while to perform. That's not necessarily a show-stopper, but it is something that might require some organizing on your behalf to time things correctly. Otherwise you might be spending weeks without Internet while you wait for a technician to come to make the necessary changes.
- Not all providers are equally fast, and the numbers they promise in their advertisement are usually pure fantasy "theoretical" speeds they rarely achieve in practice. When you want to know the *actual* speed you can expect, you will have to do some searching for some customer testimonies and independent test results.

Comment: And not all providers are as good about handling customer problems. And not all providers serve all neighborhoods -- having three major USPs available in my neighborhood, two of them on optical fiber, is a luxury.

Comment: *You write a letter and all you notice is that you suddenly pay less money per month.* No, not at all. At least not in all places I know of in the US. Typically there are 2 or 3 providers with physically separate networks, usually with totally different technology (DSL vs. Fiber vs. Coax). As opposed to electricity and natural gas (and in theory water, but in my area there is no alternate available for water/sewer) where when you change you still have the same company for the "last mile" and absolutely no change whatsoever to your physical connection, meter, etc. Even more than that, back in

Comment: the days before last-mile fiber was common, if you switched DSL providers the new provider would usually provision a separate copper pair from the local telco and require a professional install to hook it up - and that's even though the provider would have equipment colocated in the same CO where your original line terminated.

Comment: IMO, internet speeds among competitors are less and less important these days, as all of them are near or above speeds that typical home usage wouldn't notice any increase over. The difference between 50 and 100 mbps is likely unnoticeable in a typical household. Personally, I'd even consider 25 mbps to be competitive with 100 mbps.

Comment: @user26460, depends on what business you're in. My wife is an actor, and transferring a 100gb file (raw video from an interview session) to the client it was created for has been quite painful on account of that client's bandwidth being inadequate (well, that, and not having easy-to-use tooling for partial/incremental transfers available out-of-the-box to less-technical users).

Comment: My experience in the US has been that nothing about this answer is really correct. For any kind of utility. Nobody requires writing a letter these days. Some utilities can’t be changed at all - either you have it or your don’t. There’s an electric power marketplace such that you can use a web site to easily switch "providers" and your bill changes but the actual "last mile" is still serviced by the same company. For green power your bill can go up. But for ISPs it’s almost never that simple. Even if they aren’t running new cable/fiber, they almost always want to deploy their own modem/NID.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Residential *upload* speeds are almost always terrible (~10Mbps). It is more likely that your upload speed is less than your client's download.

Comment: @noslenkwah, my residential connection is gigabit symmetric -- I'm part of an 800-unit major-city downtown condominium high-rise wired with cat5e by the developers at construction time; our upstream is microwave, and rock-solid (even in storms, which has been surprising -- the last time I had a microwave connection was 20 years earlier, and it was much less robust in bad weather). It really is the client's end. (I can upload the content to Google Drive in 20 minutes; their download of that same content fails somewhere over the course of 20 hours)

Comment: @noslenkwah, ...at the risk of continuing a tangent, that very fast, very affordable connection is one of the things I pull out when talking to people who hold that HOAs and condominium associations are always a bad idea; the buying power one gets when negotiating as a bloc can be considerable.

Answer (score 3):

**YES** its a good idea to explore.

Make a list of the technical features your current ISP provides that you use.  Static IPv4 addresses, a routed block, static IPv6 prefix and how big it is, avoiding CGNAT, permission to run a mail/web/home VPN server etc.   Make sure you're not trading away something you need.

Performance at busy times also comes into it, but getting quantitative numbers for comparison can be difficult.

If you use an email address like user@spectrum.com then that will likely vanish, so you need to update to a new address.   The benefit of something like @gmail.com or other web mail providers becomes valuable here.

Other bundled services can add/subtract from the "value" too.  Analogue phone lines, TV services, fax options, cellular tie-in can also give you a bulk price with some theoretical discount, where changing one part of the service can have follow on effects.

Try `phoning/calling your current ISP and talk to them.  Don't email or use online chat.  If you get connected to a good CSR then the whole discussion can be quite rewarding.  If you get someone who can only read-the-script then ask to be transferred.

Remember it costs the provider less to keep a paying customer than to loose one to the competition and gain another.

The current provider is banking on you not going through the "hassle" of changing, and just paying more.  Banks are chronic at this, because changing one's financial details everywhere is a long process.  Changing ISPs is much easier than changing bank.

Answer (score 3):

### Your time is not worthless

Yes, for most people with decent wage, changing ISP provider every year or 2 years to profit for lower price for new customers is too much hassle. The process is not always as smooth as promised, you can end up with a few days without service in the transition period, or you can end up taking day off to be at home when the serviceman is about to come, loosing more money than you save.

Provider hopping is something more popular in low income countries, or for people on the lower end of wage pyramid. If you earn well, spending free time for your hobbies instead of calling service lines and comparing offers might be worth more than about $200 you can save.

Answer (score 1):

Is the speed and reliability the same? Do they have installation fees/costs? Are there hidden fees/costs? Do you have to pay rent on equipment? How long is the price good for? Are you stuck in a contract after that?

All good things you should likely investigate before deciding if swapping is best for you.

As others have said, you can try calling up asking for a deal, but with my personal experience recently, that doesn't help. My spectrum had bumped up to $85, so I finally decided to jump to Google Fiber and was just going to be 100% done with Spectrum regardless. But I had tried calling twice asking for a deal. No dice. HOWEVER, when I called to cancel... suddenly there was a $49.99 deal they could cut me! I already had fiber installed and wasn't changing so I declined. But if you wanted to try canceling your service (on the phone) and see if you could get a deal that way, it may be worth it. BUT if they don't offer it to you, you have to be prepared to be without internet until you get a new service hooked up. I believe spectrum will cut your internet off the day you cancel even if your service should still run for the rest of the month. So be aware and your miles may vary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check competitors (obviously) and prepare a BATNA (aka best alternative to negotiated agreement)
2. Call/visit your ISP and ask to haggle.
   If they can match the competitors offer - good. If not, take the best competitor offer.
   Remember to compare reliability - wifi/mobile is worst, cable tv internet is ok, fiber is best.

Option for unlucky folks who only have sole one provider available:

- Don't tell them they are only option.
- Haggle the price.
- If salesperson insists "this is the lowest rate we can offer", ask if they can give you more if they are charging more - bump your transfer rate to next tier, external IP or whatever 'premium' things you find valuable from them.
  (This worked for me, twice. Cable TV raising their price brackets - keeping my old price as a loyal customer was no go, but bumping my transfer rating to "acceptable" level? No problem!)

Comment: To bring in another alternative re: reliability -- microwave can be a lot more reliable now than it was 20 years ago; for a sufficiently modern implementation I'd rank it just below fiber. I'm in an 800-unit high-rise condo (prewired with cat5e during construction), our internet is via microwave (as we got a more cost-competitive offer for that than tapping into the fiber literally already running right under the building), and it's been solid even in bad weather; night and day compared to the microwave uplink my employer had around `99-2001, which went out whenever there was a bit of rain.

Comment: If your ISP is your only choice they know... No need to pretend they don't!

Comment: @user2705196 That was definitely true. However, that all fell apart in the US only within the last year or so with inexpensive cell network-based service and Starlink, with essentially a nationwide footprint.

Comment: ISP doesn't necessarily know what options you have available - they would have to query all big and small competitors all the time. Sometimes the alternative options are so bad they might as well not exist, eg. a landline internet 10 times slower and 25% more expensive than current offer.
Cell & wifi have one crucial element - they require line of sight with no obstructions. If you live in a hole, with trees all around, and your phone looses signal when calling, cell is not going to work.